# Moving multiple documents within library

Tags: 2007

I am restructuring my SharePoint folder system and need to move multiple documents at once within the same library.

For example, I have one 'bucket' library with about 1000 documents, and I would now like to filter these documents into folders within the 'bucket' library.

However, I have only found a way to do this individually - moving one document at a time. Does anyone know if there is a function to move multiple files in one go.

I am using SharePoint 2007.

Answer (score 3):

There are basically 2 methods for moving documents in SharePoint 2007.

1) Using Windows Explorer

2) Manage Content and Structure

Both of the them is well explained in this blog: [Moving files in SharePoint 2007](http://www.shareesblog.com/?p=99)

This blog has detailed steps to move files within SP 2007 including picture illustrations as posting detailed steps here would be too long.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the document library as a windows explorer folder and move the files within the document library in bulk. I believe you are using SharePoint 2007 (as tagged in the post)?. Navigate to the document library -> Click on actions -> Open with windows explorer. See [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-sharepoint-services-help/use-windows-explorer-to-look-at-files-RZ010233836.aspx?section=7)

Comment: Can you please add details to your answer about how to do that, to make it less dependent on the link (if the link breaks, your answer will not be as helpful as it could be right now)

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on whether you want a code solution or not. If you do then have a look at MSDN for SPFile.MoveTo() [MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms468280(v=office.12).aspx). If not you could use WebDAV and just cut and paste.